# Delta - replaceWhere vs Dynamic partitionOverwriteMode

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, delta-lake

trying to follow the difference between replaceWhere vs Dynamic partitionOverwriteMode.

Looking at the documentation (https://docs.databricks.com/en/delta/selective-overwrite.html), both seem to be trying to address the issues around overwriting the selected partitions.

Also as per the doc, when constraint is set to True, replaceWhere validates that all rows match the predicate, and performs an atomic replacement using overwrite semantics. If any values in the operation fall outside the constraint, this operation fails with an error by default.